# Use progress bar dialog in async task using Future in Flutter

Tags: async-await, flutter, future

I want to create common class for execute API. Now i needed to add progress dialog while executing task and after complete task dialog should be dismiss.I google lot but not get appropriate solution So help me to achieve it.

> **For Http Client i used dio plugin.**
>
> **Please help me for adding progress dialog in this class so when i create request using this class it added progress dialog while executing task. i create this type of class in java but now i want to add it in flutter.**
>
> **HttpRequest.dart**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HttpRequest {
    void post(BuildContext context,String url, dynamic data, HttpListener listener) {
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        dio.post(url, data: data)
           .then((Response<dynamic> response) {
                  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                      listener.onSuccess(response.data);
                  } else {
                      listener.onError("Error");
                  }
              })
           .catchError((Exception error) {
              listener.onError(error.toString());
            });
    }
}

abstract class HttpListener {
  void onSuccess(dynamic result);

  void onError(String error);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the context object is needed to handle stats and draw something on the screen. I believe it's better to show the progress bar in the widget, whenever an HTTP request is being called.

Comment: I can also pass instance of context there but i still didn't know how to add progress.

Comment: I have tried passing context to a service. but it's cause some issues. If you insist on passing context, use navigator to push a page with progressBar. still, I believe progress bar should be shown by the widget calls the service.,

Comment: Now i added context here in method. Is it help you ?

Comment: I wrote a code that pops a progress bar from the common class. contact my email: yamin.tashakkori atgmail. I'll send the code to you. I won't put it as an answer because it's not the correct way. contact me and we'll discuss.

Comment: @Yamin check your mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to show progressbar in widgets, not in common classes.

Use below example (using [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http)):

```
class HttpRequest {
  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

  Future post(String url, dynamic data) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(url,body: data);
    if(response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 300){
      throw new Exception('Faild');
    } else {
      return _decoder.convert(response.body);
    }
  }
}
```

The button that calls post method:

```
child: MaterialButton(onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }));
            HttpRequest _util = new HttpRequest();
            try{
              var res = await _util.post('someurl',_data);
            } catch(Exception) {
                //Handle Exception
            } finally {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a public package, future_progress_dialog, which is the opposite concept of package. 
You wanted to put progress dialog in the task. But I tried the opposite way, putting Future task into the dialog.

https://pub.dev/packages/future_progress_dialog

With this package you can make a progress dialog like this.

```
var result = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    child: FutureProgressDialog(future, 'Loading...'));
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Have been struggling with FutureBuilder for hours, but could not get it to work for my use case. Then I found this and your package fixed it in minutes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do it in fully async mode

```
        onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return const Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }));
            authenticate().then((value) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              _showErrorToast(context);
            });
          },
```